# Pagination on single post page?

Tags: posts, pagination, single

I've found many pagination tutorials/plugins that work on pages displaying a list of posts such as index.php

E.g. - http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin

However I want this to display on single post pages (single.php) so you can navigate through to the next/prev post.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I know Twenty Eleven include this functionality by default and I've come to expect it as default behavior, so I hope I'm not missing something here.

You should be able to add this to single.php by using the [previous_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) and [next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) functions.

Comment: thanks. I've already got prev/next post links. I'm trying to add a graphical style pagination to the page.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Sorry about that. I'll look around a bit.

Comment: this link might be helpful: http://www.kinocreative.co.uk/hints-and-tips/wordpress-nextprevious-post-navigation-with-images-and-inactive-links/

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in template tag for this: wp_link_pages(). It's used in Twentyeleven in `content-page.php`.